# Displaying custom post type on front page

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm creating a custom theme and I´m working with custom post types, I´m trying to loop the custom post type to display on the page but for some reason the post isn't shown.

**Custom post type**

```
/* Team Members */
function therabytes_team_post_type() {
    $labels = array (
        'name' => 'Team',
        'singular_name' => 'Team',
        'add_new' => 'Add Team Member',
        'all_items' => 'All Team Members',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add Team Member',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit Team Member',
        'new_item' => 'New Team Member',
        'view_item' => 'View Team Member',
        'search_item' => 'Search Team Member',
        'not_found' => 'Team member not found',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'Item not found in trash',
        'parent_item_colon' => 'Parent Item',
    );

    $arg = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'supports' => array(
            'title',
            'revisions'
        ),
        'taxonomies' => array(),
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'exclude_from_search' => true
    );

    register_post_type('team', $arg);
}

add_action('init', 'therabytes_team_post_type');
```

**Looping custom post types**

```
    <?php
    $teamargs = array( 'post_type' => 'team', 'posts_per_page' => 5 );
    $teamloop = new WP_Query( $teamargs );
    if(have_posts()) : ?>
    <?php
      while ( $teamloop->have_posts() ) : $teamloop->the_post();
    ?>
    <p>Custom post</p>
  <?php endwhile;?>
<?php endif;?>
```

**Template Page**

```
<?php
/*
  Template Name: Home Template
*/
get_header();
?>
<div class="team-carousel">
            <?php
            $teamargs = array( 'post_type' => 'team', 'posts_per_page' => 5 );
            $teamloop = new WP_Query( $teamargs );
            if(have_posts()) : ?>
            <?php
              while ( $teamloop->have_posts() ) : $teamloop->the_post();
            ?>
            <p>Custom post</p>
          <?php endwhile;?>
        <?php endif;?>

          <div class="flip-card">
            <div class="card team">
              <div class="front">
                <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/team/Thorsten.png" alt="">
              </div>
              <div class="back team-info">
                <p class="team-name">Thorsten Feldmann</p>
                <p class="position">Founder/CEO</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
  </div>

    <?php
      get_footer();
    ?>
```

Here i post the template page where i want to display the custom post types, i have been checking some code and i font find the reason why.

Comment: front-page is a template?

Comment: yes is a template

Comment: can you post you template code?

Comment: Yes sure there is the template page code

Comment: should i use better a template part.....or is something else what is happening ?

Comment: Do you have wp_query in the template?

Comment: aren't you just missing `$teamloop->` in the first `have_posts()` else it will look for the standard query, which might not be set, or where none exists?

Comment: @George yes there is wp_query on the template. @Stender on the code is not missing the `$teamloop` on the first `have_post()` i just forget to put on here but in the project is there

Comment: Never mind guys i found where was the problem, the post were not displaying because the container had a  `display: none; ` sorry

Comment: :-D no worries, everybody makes error 40 sometimes! (https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fejl_40)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<?php
/*
  Template Name: Home Template
*/
get_header();
?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
    <div class="team-carousel">
        <?php
        $teamargs = array( 'post_type' => 'team', 'posts_per_page' => 5 );
        $teamloop = new WP_Query( $teamargs );
        if($teamloop->have_posts()) : ?>
        <?php
          while ( $teamloop->have_posts() ) : $teamloop->the_post();
        ?>
        <p>Custom post</p>
      <?php endwhile;?>
    <?php endif;?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

      <div class="flip-card">
        <div class="card team">
          <div class="front">
        <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/team/Thorsten.png" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="back team-info">
        <p class="team-name">Thorsten Feldmann</p>
        <p class="position">Founder/CEO</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <?php
      get_footer();
    ?>
```